# Encrypt PHP script to a domain (RSA)

Tags: php, encryption

I have a php script I want to share with someone but only limit them to be able to use it on one domain.

I have found http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ - I think I can do this with RSA encryption.

How would I go about encrypting it to one domain?

Answer (score 1):

If you give a PHP script to someone there is no way you can limit its use, since the person can modify the script as he wishes before putting it into the server.  And if you give it to him encrypted, it won't be usable.

What you can do is to host your PHP script on your server and allow the person to call it remotely from his script.  However, I'm not sure if good PHP security policies would allow that.

phpseclib is a PHP implementation of ciphers and cryptographic tools, not a tool to encrypt PHP scripts.

Can you please clarify "encrypting a script to one domain", it does not mean anything to me.